# loading a html file with another html file

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a HTML page (lets say index.html) that will have a dynamic drop down menu. What i want to do is to keep my dropdown menu in a seperate html file(menu.html) so that it will be easier to maintian. What i want to know is that how to load the menu.html file within the index.html file?

I have tried with some frame examples but the menu.html file which contains the DD menu doesnot appear in the index page.

Like for example, I have tried with this in my index page but nothing appears:

```
<frameset rows="200,*" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
<frame src="menu.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize>
```

Comment: Try `<iframe src="menu.html"></iframe>` instead.

Comment: If you use the iframe tag, don't forget to add a width and height.

Comment: Better use a dynamic language for web like php. I suggest this tutorial http://tutorialzine.com/2011/08/jquery-mobile-mvc-website-part-2/

Comment: Solution available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39447411/how-to-load-nav-menu-from-an-external-file-no-wamp-all-code-must-be-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay in HTML, uses : `<iframe src="menu.html" width=400 height=200></iframe>`
with the width and height you want.

But the best is to use PHP by including the file like this : 
`<?php
  include('menu.html');
?>`

But it is your choice at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the column width as described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html).

```
<frameset cols="100%">
  <frameset rows="200, *">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use php you can simply include it. here is a link to a tutorial to show you how to do this [tutorial](http://www.apaddedcell.com/how-automatically-include-your-header-navigation-and-footer-every-page). If you don't use php then ignore this answer, but far better this than frames which have a lot of restrictions on how the content might be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and the .load() function for this purpose.

Example:

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#menu").load("menu.html");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can handle it

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#divId").load("b.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="divId"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```